# Upload e Download de arquivos - Open source

Tags: php, html5, css3

Alguém tem um sistema de upload e download de arquivos open source?! Um que de pra manipular os arquivos, como por exemplo separando-os por pastas, movendo-os para outras pastas, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da uma olhada nesse plugin:

[CKFinder](https://cksource.com/ckfinder)

Aparentemente, esse é o mais completo, porém ele é premium, o que eu utilizo é o FileRun, mas é meio chato pra fazer ele rodar:

[FileRun](http://www.filerun.com/)